# How Do I Create/Edit a Discount Schedule to Discount Based on the Number of Product Options in a Bundle

Tags: cpq

We need a discount rule to discount product options within a bundle based on the number of products within the bundle on a quote.

For example, you could have the following bundle:

**ABC Bundle (parent)** has the following components:

Component 1

Component 2

Component 3

Component 4

If the bundle above contains the following number of Components we need the following discounts to be applied to the components within that bundle:

1. if it contains 2 components - 5% discount should be applied to the components within that particular quote line bundle.
2. if it contains 3 components - 7.5% discount should be applied to the components within that particular quote line bundle.
3. if it contains 4 or more components - 10% discount should be applied to the components within that particular quote line bundle.

I am attaching screenshots of the current Discount Schedule that we need to tweak in order to calculate the discounts or rebuild if needed. The last screenshot is what they look like on the quote line.
We are new to bundles and discount schedules.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any help on what needs to be tweaked or how we do this would be great. We do not want to use the standard Quantity field that most discount bundles are based on. We want to count the options and discount based on that.

On a side note, would it be possible to create a new tag called Discount Schedules? Or should we?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by creating a "count" field on the product option for a summary variable. Then used that summary variable for determining the Discount.